# Windows Server 2012 R2 - Force Terminal Server users to print with a specific configuration

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, printing, terminal-server

I have a machine with Windows Server 2012 R2, and I configured some printers in this computer with the Admin account. I also have some terminal server users. However, **although printers are configured to print in grayscale, terminal server users will print in color (because is the default configuration)**. There are 1000 users and I have to configure their printers one by one to print in grayscale with this configuration.

**Is there a way to force regular terminal server users to use Administrator configuration?**

Thanks in advance, regards.

**EDIT:**

I found an easy way by using a Powershell Script that is launched when a user is logged on:

```
Import-Module PrintManagement
Set-PrintConfiguration -PrinterName "B/W Printer 1" -Color 0
Set-PrintConfiguration -PrinterName "B/W Printer 2" -Color 0
Set-PrintConfiguration -PrinterName "Color Printer" -Color 1
Set-PrintConfiguration -PrinterName "B/W Printer 3" -Color 0
```

Comment: another option could be usign Ricoh's Print&Share www.printandshare.info we use it here on Terminal Server. we have a set of profiles that we make available per security group in active directory and did a specific roll out. Now WE tell users how to print. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

2 Options I can think of, one generic and one printer specific.

1: Create a Log on script that sets up the print configuration.
2: Change the printer settings to pull the default settings from the printer, and configure the printer to use Grey-Scale by default.

The first one should be more printer driver related, the second will be specific to the type of printer you use. Most of the copiers that businesses use have their own print configuration options that are installed alongside the driver. You'll need to speak to your hardware supplier or Google the printer type for the documentation on driver configuration.